# What is the "My Contacts" range in this Telegram settings page?

Tags: privacy, telegram-messenger

I want to stay very private on Telegram. Here is a `My Contacts` toggle that I must check unless I switch to "Everybody".

What is the definition of "My Contacts" here? I don't want to be found by anyone by my number, even someone who is in this "My Contacts" scope.

Thanks for any tips!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You would have to register on Telegram without using your phone number.

As it is right now, as long ask the person has you in their contacts and you have them in your contacts, then you will show up. (1:1 ratio both parties have each other as contacts)

If you are outside of the states you can look more into the option of registering without a phone number over at Fragment.com *(Trade IDs not tied to a SIM card which allow logging into Telegram with your blockchain account.)*

Never used it, but that's all I know as far as options go currently with how Telegram works.

Or the other option would be to remove all of your contacts, not really ideal but that would work as well.

Comment: Thanks! Did you mean this one? https://fragment.com/ It seems that I can't buy it at once, I need to bid some tokens and wait.

Comment: Yes, that's the site from what I've read. I can't access it without using a VPN (in the states it's currently being blocked by the site). There are a few articles out there that I've read about it but haven't used it. Good luck with it, hope it helps.